# How to implement event delegation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to disable `copy` and `contextmenu` for a subset of elements in my app (I know it's easy to bypass, but it's a requirement I need to meet).

In vanilla JS, I achieve this by having a unique classname (eg - `no-select`), and attach the `copy`/`contextmenu` events to the document, then test that target element for that classname.

I was wondering if there was a standard way to implement class-based event delegation with React, or should I just do this outside of the React realm.

The main benefits for me for doing this within the React realm are:

- I don't need to care about cleanup.
- Since this is a localized requirement, doing this for the entire document seems like an overkill.
- Would rather not have side-methods for doing things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle React event delegation with stopPropagation()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566781/handle-react-event-delegation-with-stoppropagation)